# Is a power adapter with a loose prong safe to use?

Tags: electrical

[image] ok so while moving my couch I accidentally unplugged my adapter plug in a rough way and now one prong is messed up as seen in the picture it's shorter now and can be pushed up and down is this safe to use ?  can it be repaired the broken prong can't seem to stay in place

Comment: "Safe" is a subjective term. I'd continue to use it, but be aware of any arcing  that occurs and take it as a warning.

Comment: It would probably cost maybe $5 to replace. I wouldn't hesitate to replace it.

Comment: There's a million different designs for these wall warts. Usually it takes a couple good swift whacks on the side seams to break the glue so you can look inside and see if the prong movement poses a danger. Once in there you might even be able to fix the problem and glue the thing back together. Unless you know what you're doing, it's safer to toss the busted unit, and get a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several risks here. The first three I can think of are:

- If the prong is pushed too far into the case it may touch other parts causing a short circuit, possibly putting line voltage on the output. Ideally it would be designed internally to prevent this possibility, but you don't know.
- If the prong is also able to be pulled out, then unplugging the adapter could leave the prong in the outlet, resulting in live exposed metal.
- Plugging it in might work but make poor contact, resulting in overheating at the plug (probably not) or intermittent operation.

It is unlikely that the adapter can be repaired adequately. Instead, purchase a replacement of the same voltage, current, polarity, and output plug type.

Comment: +1 especially for the second bullet point. Those are not polarized prongs, so it could easily end up sticking in- and then protruding from the hot terminal, depending on its orientation when plugged in. It should be replaced before the issue gets forgotten about and somebody ends up getting a nasty zap.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ! I'm better of getting a replacement adapter